# Solve $2x-1 \le x^2$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My book tells me that the solution is $(-\infty, \infty)$. But why is that the solution if you get $(x-1)^2 \ge 0$ after you finish factoring the equation?

Shouldn't the answer be $(1,\infty){}{}{}$?

Comment: all squares are nonnegative. $(x-1)^2$ is a square.

Comment: When $x=-27$, what is $(x-1)^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: for which $x$ does the inequality hold? if $(x-1)<0$ then $(x-1)(x-1)=(x-1)^2$ will give you a positive number, the same if $(x-1)>0$. And if $x=1$ then the inequality still holds.

Also be careful because you could be running into the mistake of saying: well since $(x-1)^2\geq 0$ then $\sqrt{(x-1)^2}\geq \sqrt{0}$, then $x\geq 1$, which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

$$2x-1\le x^2\iff 0\le x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

simplifying $2x-1\le x^2$ we obtain $0\le (x-1)^2$ and this is true, since a square of a real number is not negative.